# Is there any way to use Cycles for 3D data visualization?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, volumetrics, csv

I have a CSV file containing coordinates for stars in a galaxy and I want to plot them through volumetric data inside a cube. I have tried the voxel data type in blender 2.79 with blender render (it doesnt works with Cycles) but cant find any way to implement that in 2.8.

I have produced a mandlebulb fractal using the coordinates inside the volume of a cube and then manupulated the density according to the mathematical formula.
I just want a way to get the coordinates from the CSV file into separate X, Y, Z nodes.